# How to capture group A or B, but not both?

Tags: regex

I want to make a regex to capture a string of format `test1 anything here` or `anything here test2`, but **not** `test1 anything here test2`.

Is there a way to write a regex for this? Basically, I want something like `/^(test1 )?(.*)$( test2)?/i`, but preventing test1 and test2 from both appearing. Also, my example is wrong because it never gets past the 2nd capturing group... How can I do this?

Edit: I want to be able to capture the `anything here` part, so it needs to be inside its own capturing group.

Comment: What is the regex flavor, BTW?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm I'm not quite sure... I want it for hubot, so I'm guessing the flavor is coffeescript/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alternative of negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(test1 (((?!test2).)*)$)|(^(((?<!test1).)*)test2)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7VbkZm/2/)

Explaination:

- `(test1 ((?!test2).)*$)` find lines with `test1` and no test2:

  - `test1` matches text `test1`
  - `(?!test2)` negative lookahead - match place unless there is `test2` ahead
  - `((?!test2).)*` is a tempered greedy token (matching as much as possible until `test2` text)
  - `$` end-of-line assertion to assure there is no tailing`test2`

The second part of the alternative is similar, but we check there is no leading `test1` using negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`

Worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/580346

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about something that I needed though... Could you please see the edit I did to the question?

Comment: Updated (added groups). Unfortunately it will not work in JS (lookbehind is not supported). I'll update when I find a better idea.